# How to get number of locks acquired by my `MySQL` Query?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, locking

How to get number of locks acquired by my `MySQL` update query?

**Example query** : `update employees set store_id = 0 where store_id = 1;`

Comment: what is your mean of 'locks' ?

Comment: I think `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` will be useful as you'll see what is locked. It is usually a very helpful approach for debugging the "The number of locks exceeds the lock table size." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to get the number of locks acquired by following set of MySQL statements.

```
begin;
update employees set store_id = 0 where store_id = 1;
show engine innodb status\G
commit;
```

EDIT :

We can also get lock details using following query for current transaction.

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_locks;
```